# What are the differences and the use of the ASP.NET`, .NET Framework and Common Language Runtime (CLR)?

Tags: asp.net, clr, .net-framework-version

I'm a bit confused about the difference between `ASP.NET`, `.NET Framework` and `Common Language Runtime (CLR)`. If anyone can give a simple, bullet-point explanation of the difference, please?

This application error page shows `.NET Framework 4.030319` and `ASP.NET 4.8`, but I am not sure whether they are false positives.

I did a bit of searching and got the impression that `ASP.NET` and `.NET Framework` would have to run the same version for them to work? I.E., they cannot run two separate variants of each other?

Is version `4.030319` from the application error page referring to the `.NET Framework version`, or the `CLR version`?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET = you are doing web development, and you use .net code.

.net framework. That is the set of tools you writing code with, and the system that can "run + consume" your .net code. So you might write some .net code for the desktop. You need + use the .net framework.

You might write some .net code for say a web application. So that's called asp.net. (but again, it just needs the .net framework to work and run and execute that code you write. So the .net framework can be much though of a a "runtime".

Just like say you need VB6 runtimes to execute VB6 code, or say the Access runtime to run + execute ms-access code and applications.

The same idea applies to the .net framework. So if you going to write asp.net system (a web based system), then the server side code will need to support + run the .net framework.

In ALL OF these cases, the code you write in .net (c#, vb.net) is compiled down to "IL" or so called intermediate language. And once this occurs, then the CLR (common language runtime) can then/now execute that code.

So you might use the .net framework to write desktop software. (either winforms - (older), or the newer WPF system. (but in BOTH cases, you still writing .net code, and in you still need the .net framework in both cases to write + run that desktop software.

If you say you are writing asp.net software? Well then I will KNOW that you are using the .net framework, but you are writing a WEB BASED application.

So, quite much above summarizes the questions here.

Because you can write web based software (asp.net) and desktop software (winforms or WPF) then when you talking to me, you need to use the appropriate term. If you say asp.net, then I know this is web based, I know you not using say PHP or some other web system or so called web "stack" to create that web site.

You can write desktop software, web software with Visual Studio and you be using the so called .net framework to achieve this goal in both cases.

Of course asp.net and web based systems are VERY different then the desktop - so just like a dog and horse are VERY different, then of course web based software is VAST different then say desktop software - but you can use the .net framework and write .net code in both cases.

However, by using the correct term, then the context is important. If you using asp.net, then OBVIOUSLY you not using desktop controls from the .net framework, but would be using web based controls from the .net framework. (and again such controls are vast different - despite the fact that you writing C# or vb.net code in both cases.

As for .net 4.0. Well they try to keep things compatibility. So 4.0, 4.5, 4.7 etc.? They ALL LIVE under the .net 4.0 folder. So that "4.0 bla bla bla" can mean 4.0 and upwards in the 4 series.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes more sense than it did before :)